# GCP Marketplace base image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am investigating what it would take to make our application available in the GCP Marketplace.  I came across a note in the Marketplace docs that say to start with "one of Google's supported base public images."  Is this a requirement, or just general instructions?

https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm/build-vm-image

Our application uses a buildroot image, and would take some work to get it to run on one of the base CentOS/COOS/Ubuntu images.

Comment: Basically, you can do what you want. This final image will need to be approved.  However, I cannot comment on if a BuildRoot image will work in Google Cloud. The docs state: "We recommend you start with creating an image in your development project, and then move it to your public project after your Google Partner Engineer has verified the image."

Comment: We are able to start a GCE VM off our buildroot image, so that isn't a problem.  I hoped to be able to get an answer before trying to get started with a Google Partner Engineer, to see if we had to switch our base image or not.

Comment: The documentation states: "you need to complete these steps ... Use one of Google's supported base public images to create a VM and install your application-specific packages and configs." https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm/build-vm-image If you have further questions regarding the documentation, speak to your Google Partner Engineer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation [What is Google Cloud Marketplace?](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs):

> Google Cloud Marketplace lets you quickly deploy functional software
>   packages that run on Google Cloud Platform.

There are two ways **to add your software to Marketplace**:

> **You can suggest new software packages** or provide feedback on the
>   existing offerings **through the feedback link at the bottom of the**
>   [Google Cloud Marketplace page](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace).

and

> **To sell your software on Google Cloud Marketplace, you must become a
>   Technology Partner.** For information on becoming a partner, see the
>   [Google Cloud Technology Partners page](https://cloud.google.com/partners/become-a-partner/technology-track). For information on the
>   solutions that you can sell on Google Cloud Marketplace, see the
>   [Google Cloud Marketplace partners documentation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners).

When you deploy software from Marketplace it usually uses Deployment Manager. You can find more information in the documentation [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager). For [example](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/using-images-from-other-projects-for-vm-instances) you can create deployment that uses image from some project. In addition, please check [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/best-practices).

**EDIT** As it was suggested by *@John Hanley*, you software will be verified and should be approved.